# javac ignoring @SuppressWarnings("all")

Tags: java, annotations, compiler-warnings

I currently have an Enum, which has a constructor that can take null and contains with the following SuppressWarning annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public enum TheEnum {
...
AN_ENUM_VALUE(null),
...
...
private TheEnum(TheEnum ... args) {
    if (args != null){
        ...
        ...
    }
...
}
```

I'm currently using MyEclipse workbench 10.6, and it seems to pick up the annotation fine. During a compilation on a dev machine, however, I get warnings related to the 'TheEnum' class.

The strange this is that within the project, there are @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") all over the place, and the compiler manages to pick these up and ignore them just fine.

Because of legacy issues, we have to use JDK 1.5.0_17 to compile, but it looks like it should pick up the "all" suppression:

```
[root@xxx]:/opt/jdk1.5.0_17/bin# ./javac -X
  ...
  -Xlint:{all,deprecation,unchecked,fallthrough,path,serial,finally,-deprecation,-   unchecked,-fallthrough,-path,-serial,-finally}Enable or disable specific warnings
```

any suggestions as to where I should look to see why 'all' is being ignored?

Comment: **They (compilers) are, however, free to emit a warning if an annotation contains an unrecognized warning name.** but this is not the case !

Answer (score -2):

Don't use it in the first place.

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
```

says, **you are doing something wrong**. I would cancel a contract ASAP with any developer developing code like this. Warnings are there for a reason, and a blanket ignore says "I don't care if my code actually works" like nothing else. This is the total opposite to writing unit tests somewhat: blanket disabling the compiler checks.

Judging from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options "all" might be an eclipse extension. Sun/Oracle Java 6 compiler probably only supports the following values: `unchecked`, `path`, `serial`, `finally`, `fallthrough` and `deprecation`.

Comment: Ok, will handle it manually in this case - to explain, I was trying to implement a hierarchal enum similar to http://java.dzone.com/articles/enum-tricks-hierarchical-data, and TheEnum(null) representing a base type felt preferable to TheEnum(new TheEnum[]{}).

Comment: ouch, that looks like a **really really bad hack**. How about using objects? You know, with inheritance, interfaces and so. Instead of hacking a non-safe multi-inheritance yourself with *arrays*.

Comment: Hmm, I went looking for this stuff because the code that's spewing out the thousands of warnings for us is generated dynamically by ANTLR. So I guess the developer developing the code is essentially Terence Parr. I have wondered for a long time why people who write compilers tend to have the worst coding styles around. lol

Comment: It is scary to see how many people downvote the warning to *not* blindly suppress all warnings... Warnings are there for a reason, and "disable *all* sanity checks" has never been a good idea.

Comment: IMO, bad idea are unsolicited style advises and guesses at what the user may be doing wrong if they need to ask the question. `@SuppressWarnings("all")` may be considered perfectly fine on code generated by a 3rd party library that you have no control over. May be or may be not, but that's different discussion. The question is clear and the fact that "all" is an extension and not recognized by javac is the correct answer.

Comment: Steves It's been a while but if you posted and 2 jobs later but if you posted your suggestion I would give it the accepted answer